# QGIS project out of alignment with OSM

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap

I have a project with a CRS set to ESRI:102400. It contains an OpenStreetMap layer, added from XYZ Tiles, with a CRS of EPSG:3857. When I open the file in QGIS running on a Mac (Mac OS 10.15.7, QGIS 3.16.4), the base map lines up perfectly with other layers whose CRS is the same as the project.

However, when I open the same file on a machine running Windows (Windows 10 Pro, QGIS 3.16.13), the base map is now out of alignment with all the other layers by about 80 metres. What's going on, and how can I make everything align?

[image: Image showing layer file out of alignment with OSM base map]

Comment: Can you share your project & data? Just like this, it's difficult to say what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the offer of help. What's the best way for me to share a project on here?

Comment: You can't share it here - upload to a cloud and share the link here

Comment: @babel Thanks, link is here, to a project and a layer file. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11_0jjCm9Q4orKvZC8Qs6sI3BhSn4nJTU?usp=sharing